# When a dll is loaded into memory, which part(s) can be shared between processes?

Tags: dll, operating-system

I meet a question about the interview test:

```
When a dll is loaded into memory, which part(s) can be shared between processes?
A. code segment
B. static variable global variable
C. external difinitions and references for linking
D. BSS segment
```

who can give me an answer and a clear explation?

Answer (score 0):

Processes are actually isolated programs running multiple threads in an OS. Generally operating system policy says, All processes are memory isolated from each other.

**Code Segment** : *[NOT SHARED]*
**BSS and Static Fields** : *[NOT SHARED]*
Reason is very simple, why a operating system allow process A to access process B's binary? that's security and memory protection violation. process A could corrupt (if write access is given) process B memory.

what about **External Definitions**?
Here comes the interesting part, External definitions could be statically or dynamically linked.
statically linked library implies definitions are linked at compiled time and programs binary contains It's machine code.
dynamically linked implies definitions are linked just after user commands to load any program in memory. OS calls dynamic library loader to resolve external dependencies of the program by providing shared object's path.
This shared object is cached by operating system in a different page frame, and every time when a program demands for this library, It simply copy It's page frame to process's virtual memory; and do required dynamic linking. This way multiple process have same binary of a single library.
It save RAM memory and time in loading library from disk, Also dynamic linking reduces binary size of the program.
It is also possible that the OS choose to load library again from disk, and thus make two copies of same library. This is a part of dynamic linking operation. I don't go into more depth, but if you are really interested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker or just ping me in comments section.
But regarding BSS and static fields, It is again not shared; Whenever a write operation is performed on such region (which is shared). Operating System create a new copy of that region for the other process. This makes sure that both process have their own copy of BSS and static fields.